# Displayiing BIG CSV File as Table

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I want to read a big file with csv-data (>1 GB, export from an ERP System) and provide a table interface for the data.

In fact, I have a good working table class. This works in this (abstract) fashion:

- a table row which is a vector for the column data
- a vector for the rows.

To read the big files this goes in memory problems, I think because the vector does need the whole memory at once on the heap. So I created a new class with has only pointers to strings in the column like this:

- a table row which is a `vector<string *>` for the column data
- a `vector<row>` for the rows.

This works better. It has about 1/3 less memory footprint on the heap. I think the separated string data fits in some holes on the heap ;-)

But if the data gets bigger, the memory problem is also there.

To read the file and convert it takes about 2 minutes.

I tried SQLLite, but the import is very slow. Reading the big file (about 3000000 lines) and insert them, takes about 15 hours. I know I can speed up this a lot, but i do not really know if this is the solution. BTW:The sqlite browser crashes during import such a file!

Does anyone else have such problems or do you know a good way to manage the memory for such BIG-Data-Tables? The table is a look up table for some tasks so it should fit into the memory at once, if possible.

Currently I am working with Visual Studio C++ 2012.

Comment: Are you generating a 64-bit executable or 32-bit?  Any insight/restrictions on the number of fields or their length?  Do any have internal escaping/quoting?  Anyway, there's no point having `string*`s unless many are empty and `sizeof string` > `sizeof string*` (which it might be, but you should check).  Memory mapping and tracking indices may be an option, and if not it'll be more space efficient storing a `vector<Row>` where `struct Row` contains a `string` and how-ever many indices therein.

Comment: I think your pb with SQLite comes from their memory based implementation of the commit.  Write your own SQLLite buffered import:  read a couple of rows (f.ex by group of 10 000), start a transaction write a couple of rows, commit transaction, etc...

Comment: @Christophe I googled about the speed for SQLite and found some examples like your recommendation. But then i have to integrate the table in SQLLite. I would prefer a pure C++ Solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing to much about your problem, here is what I would do when I had a similar situation 10 years ago and it took 36 hours to dump into a Oracle database, this more than halved to to 16:

Create a bunch of buffers (say 10,000 lines of data) and have a thread read in the data into these in a circular fashion.

Then have another thread start actually working on the data.

Admittedly this only works if each row is independent of others.

[Edit: This link about memory locality may help.](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html) Essentially use `[]` instead of `vectors`.

Comment: It is written in 32 Bit. The lines are(can) depending on other lines. There are article numbers, partly grouped together with other lines. Reading (2 minutes) ist fast enought, the problem is more the crash without exeptions if there are to much "text" involved to put in the table.

Comment: In fact there are also a lot of empty strings. So using <string *> instead of <string> only saves some (1/3) memory.Helps a little.

Comment: BTW: There are a lot of CSV Tools out there. I tried several. All of them had problems to read the file at all or took more than 1/2 hour only to view the file. Notepad++ remarks (File is too big..), but i have the good old 010 Editor which works fine mit pure editing the text.

Answer (score 0):

[DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) is the perfect tool that will load multi-million lines of CSV into an in-memory table to run SQL queries on it.

This multi-platform software can ingest 15 CSV files with 12.6M lines each (189M in total) in less than a minute on a normal desktop computer with only 32GB of RAM